# Is there a way to track document editing time in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-integration

We have few content writer that are paid by the hour. And they submit their documents on sharepoint. They usually bill 10X more than their actual time(We were even billed 30 hrs for a document copied from online). Instead of downloading and checking the total time spent editing on the document and adding to the time. Is there a direct way of pulling data as a field for document library.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is - no. There is no such field a SharePoint library that contains the amount of time spent on the document. You might need a different tool for tracking time spent working.

For example.

- https://screenshotmonitor.com/
- https://hubstaff.com/

P.S. I have nothing to do with these companies.